# Wanted to upload Large files (around 5 to 10 gb) to the AWS via ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, amazon-web-services, file-upload

I need to develop the feature to upload large files to the AWS in ASP .Net application.

I understood that webserver has a restriction of uploading maximum 4 GB files by configuring `maxAllowedContentLength` to max value.

This feature is used mainly by the system admins.

How can we implement this in ASP.Net appliaction? or 
is it better to use windows service which sits on the admin machine and processes the files sequentially and uploads to the AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems we cann't upload more than 2GB files via webserver.
We can use browser upload directly using signatures.

followed the below link for browser upload

https://github.com/floatingfrisbee/amazonfileupload